# I don't understand output this code. (Map)

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I don't understand this output.

cause I created 4 other keys(Bottle b1, b2, b3, b4).

4 keys have other attributes.

So, I think this code print 4 outputs.

But this code print only 3 outputs.

Why????

```
package map;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TreeMapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bottle b1 = new Bottle("red", 15);
        Bottle b2 = new Bottle("black", 10);
        Bottle b3 = new Bottle("white", 20);
        Bottle b4 = new Bottle("green", 10);
//      Bottle b4 = new Bottle("red", 10);
//      Bottle b4 = new Bottle("red", 11);

        TreeMap<Bottle, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<Bottle, Integer>();
        treeMap.put(b1, 10);
        treeMap.put(b2, 15);
        treeMap.put(b3, 5);
        treeMap.put(b4, 20);

        for (Map.Entry<Bottle, Integer> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}

class Bottle implements Comparable<Bottle> {
    String name;
    int size;

    Bottle(String name, int size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Bottle o) {
        return this.size - o.size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name + " bottle";
    }
}
```

if `Bottle b4 = new Bottle("green", 10);` or `Bottle b4 = new Bottle("red", 10);`

result is

```
black bottle - 20
red bottle - 10
white bottle - 5
```

but if `Bottle b4 = new Bottle("red", 11);`

result is

```
black bottle - 15
red bottle - 20
red bottle - 10
white bottle - 5
```

I don't understand this output...

Comment: It might be because you should override equals and hashcode for your Bottle class.

Comment: But I think hashcode, equals not need.
cause, Bottle is (new Object) key.

Comment: Bottle is Key, Integer value is Value.

I know Map needs other Keys.

And I think b1, b2, b3, b4 are not same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeMap` takes into consideration equality of keys that you used in your custom comparator. Because two of your bottles are equal (because they have the same size value), one is replaced. In this case: green is replaced by black.

Take a look what treeMap.put returns:

> Returns:
>       the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put-K-V-

If we output what `treeMap.put(...)` returns, we'll see that we get four `nulls` and in the last case, we get `15`. So putting `b4` replaces `b2` because they are equal:

```java
System.out.println(treeMap.put(b1, 10));
System.out.println(treeMap.put(b2, 15));
System.out.println(treeMap.put(b3, 5));
System.out.println(treeMap.put(b4, 20));
```

gives:

```
null
null
null
15
```